# How to change the footer image in each page of xsl-fo according to certain condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Is there a way to change the footer image in each page of xsl-fo according to certain condition?

Comment: is the condition related to the page number (say if page 1 show image A, if page 2 show image B) or is it something related to the data?

Comment: the condition is according to data ,if certain data if changes we need a different footer image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use markers, basically they allow you to change the side regions (before, after, start, end) based on the contents of the body XML. I use them all the time for running heads, but the principle will be the same for what you want.

A simple example can be found at http://www.renderx.com/tutorial.html#Markers, or you can get more detail at Dave Pawson's (Author of the O'Reilly XSL-FO book) site http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/markers.html